# lucky sevens, sum of 3 consecutive numbers in array == 7

Tags: python

> Write a function lucky_sevens(numbers), which takes in an array of
>   integers and returns true if any three consecutive elements sum to 7.

Why isn't this producing an output of True? The last 3 values sum = 7.

```
 def lucky_sevens(numbers):
      x, y = 0, 3
      sum_of_numbers = sum(numbers[x:y])
      while (sum_of_numbers != 7) and (y < len(numbers)):
        x = x + 1
        y = y + 1
      if sum_of_numbers == 7:
        return True
      else:
        return False

    print(lucky_sevens([1,2,3,4,5,1,1]))
```

Comment: You never changed `sum_of_numbers`.

Comment: Wouldn't the while function change the values of x and y, changing the value of sum_of_numbers?

Comment: Why would changing the values of and y change the value of sum_of_numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that when the function first gets called the `sum_of_numbers` variable gets assigned the value of the sum of the first 3 values in the list, and never gets updated with the new `x`,`y` values, you'd probably want to create a callback function to achieve that behavior.

As it stands, you'll need to move the `sum` statement into the `while` loop so the sum gets updated with the new `x`,`y` values:

```
def lucky_sevens(numbers):
    result = False
    x, y = 0, 3

    while (y <= len(numbers)):
        if sum(numbers[x:y]) == 7:
            result = True
            break
        x += 1
        y += 1
    return result

print(lucky_sevens([1,2,3,4,5,1,1]))
```

Comment: You can say `return True` and remove the `break` statement

Answer (score 1):

How about something as simple as

```
    def lucky_sevens(numbers):

        for x in range(len(numbers) - 2):

            if sum(numbers[x:x+3]) == 7:

                return True

        return False
```

---

Or with your original code, just cleaned up a little bit.

```
def lucky_sevens(numbers):

    if len(numbers) < 3:
        return False

    x, y = 0, 3

    sum_of_numbers = sum(numbers[x: y])

    while sum_of_numbers != 7 and y < len(numbers):
        x += 1
        y += 1
        sum_of_numbers = sum(numbers[x: y])

    if sum_of_numbers == 7:
        return True
    return False
```

Your error came in your while loop. As you were looping, `sum_of_numbers` was staying constant. Instead, you have to update it for every new `x` and `y` within the while loop.

Also some repetitive stuff like `else: return False`, can be simplified to `return False`, as it can only get to that line if `sum_of_numbers == 7` is False.

Finally `x = x + 1` can be written in the more common shorthand `x += 1`, the same going with `y = y + 1`.

Comment: This will produce an incorrect result for `lucky_sevens([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 7])`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Fixed

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: Your cleaned up version will return True if `numbers = [3,4]`, I think.

Comment: @DSM Fixed, now you must enter at least 3 numbers

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do the trick:

```
def lucky_sevens(numbers):
    if len(numbers) < 3:
        return False
    return 7 in [sum(numbers[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(numbers)-2)]

print(lucky_sevens([1,2,3,4,5,1,1]))
# True
```

The list comprehension will move through your list 3 numbers at a time and compute the sum of each set of three integers.  If `7` is in that list, then there are 3 consecutive numbers that sum to `7`.  Otherwise, there isn't.

The one caveat is that doing this sort of list comprehension requires that the list have more than 3 elements in it.  That's why the if statement is there.

If you wanted to use your original code though, you just have to make a few adjustments.  Your logic was all there, just needs a little cleaning.

```
def lucky_sevens(numbers):
  x, y = 0, 3
  sum_of_numbers = sum(numbers[x:y])
  while (sum_of_numbers != 7) and (y < len(numbers)):
    x = x + 1
    y = y + 1
    sum_of_numbers = sum(numbers[x:y])
  if sum_of_numbers == 7:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

You simply needed to redo the `sum` within your `while` loop.  That way, `sum_of_numbers` updates with each loop and each new selection of indices.

Comment: If you replace the listcomp by a generator expression -- parentheses instead of brackets -- then you'll get short-circuiting.

Answer (score 0):

This code returns the consecutive elements in the Array whose sum is 7 and index of initial element.

```
  function lucky_seven(arr){
    let i=0;
    let lastIndex = 0;
    if(arr.length < 3){
      return false;
    }
    while(i <= lastIndex){
      let sum = 0;
      lastIndex = i + 3;
      let subArr = arr.slice(i,lastIndex);
      if(subArr.length === 3) {
        sum = subArr.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur);
        if(sum === 7){
          return {
            subArr: subArr,
            index: i
          };
        }
        i++;
      } else{
        return false;
     }
    }
  }
lucky_seven([3,2,1,4,2])
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used this:

```
 def lucky_sevens(numbers):
        x = 0
        y = False
        for i in numbers:
            if i == 7:
                x += 7
                if x == 21:
                    y = True
            else:
                x = 0
        return y
```

Comment: Are you checking for 3 consecutive 7s in the code? You need to check if 3 consecutive numbers result in a sum of 7. For ex: 5 + 1 + 1 = 7 in OP's example above.

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(l):
    if len(l) < 3:
        return False
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if i+3 <= len(l):
            if sum(l[i:i+3]) == 7:
                return True
            continue
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: if you change the first for loop to be `len(l)-2`, you can eliminate a few lines of code. Then you don't need to check for `#if i+3 <= len(l):`. Also you don't need the `continue` statement and you don't need the final `else` statement. Instead align the `return False` to `for i in range(len(l)-2)`. That will reduce your code by a few lines

Comment: Thanks! Also, I am unable to post the code with indentation. Is there a trick or method to post the code with indentation

Comment: Use the {} option to move the whole block and indent

Answer (score 0):

There are some very interesting responses here. Thought I will share my work as well.

```
def lucky_seven(num_list):
    if len(num_list) < 3: return False
    return any([True if sum(num_list[i:i+3]) == 7 else False for i in range(len(num_list)-2)])

print ('lucky seven for [1,2,3] is          :',lucky_seven([1,2,3]))
print ('lucky seven for [3,4] is            :',lucky_seven([3,4]))
print ('lucky seven for [3,4,0] is          :',lucky_seven([3,4,0]))
print ('lucky seven for [1,2,3,4,5,1,1] is  :',lucky_seven([1,2,3,4,5,1,1]))
print ('lucky seven for [1,2,3,4,-2,5,1] is :',lucky_seven([1,2,3,4,-2,5,1]))
```

The output of this will be:

```
lucky seven for [1,2,3] is          : False
lucky seven for [3,4] is            : False
lucky seven for [3,4,0] is          : True
lucky seven for [1,2,3,4,5,1,1] is  : True
lucky seven for [1,2,3,4,-2,5,1] is : True
```